# How to build my own specific type in C#?

Tags: c#

There are many different types in C# with different signatures,
how I can build a type that can accept just specific values,
for example boolean type accept True or False.
I want to build a type that accepts just three values: A, B, or C.
I defined a class:

```
class Status
{
     .....
}
```

//in Main()

```
public static void Main()
{
   Status s= a; //any other value except (a, b, or c) throw compiler error.

}
```

enter code here

Comment: Sounds like an enum: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

Comment: Maybe you want an enum. It's hard to tell with so little detail in the question. If your values can be represented internally as some integral type (e.g. `int`), then `enum` is the way to go. Otherwise, you need to be more clear about your question and what you expect the values of this type to look like. Note that in any case, you will be stuck specifying the type name along with the value; only built-in types get the compiler's special implied-type treatment like numeric literals, bool values, etc.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Your last point is not true, using operator overloading you can allow assignment from another type into your type, e.g `public static implicit operator Status(string value)` would let you do `Status status = "something";`.

Comment: @Lloyd: you are describing implicit type conversion (and presumably referring to explicit conversion by implication), which is completely different from what I describe. I'm talking about an actual type _literal_ that the compiler understands. In your example, the best you could do is overload an _existing_ literal syntax; in many cases, this would require the use of a string and a run-time-executed parser, which is hardly the same as the compiler embedding the _actual value_ in the compiled code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an enumerated type:

```
enum Something
{
    A,
    B,
    C
}
```

You can then just do:

```
Something value = Something.A;
```

There are other interesting things you can do with enums as well, so you might want to read the [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) documentation on MSDN.

This is the simplest approach. Failing that you'd probably need to define sealed types for `A`, `B` and `C` and then for the `Status` type you'd need to do some operator overloading to allow them to be assigned.